# WSO2 API Manager: PUT and OPTIONS invocations fail at the Gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

We are trying to implement CORS support in our APIs, and it we are getting an error from API Manager that is exactly the same as what is described [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-962).

We are using API Manager 1.3.

Can someone confirm that there is no way to support OPTIONS with API Manager 1.3?  We don't want to upgrade to 1.4 at this time.

Answer (score 0):

There was another issue which we found when using PUT and OPTIONS method from APIs as described in [1].

This was fixed with AM 1.4.0.Hence better option is to upgrade to 1.4.0 as it contains fix for both your mentioned issue and mine mentioned one.And additionally AM 1.4.0 contains several new features with it.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNAPSE-919

Thanks;